# sort, unique, erase does not work

Tags: c++, boost, unique, erase

I have a

```
std::vector<int> gid;
```

that contains non ordered integers. I want to sort, make unique values, and erase the repeated integers. I tried with the following codes:

```
std::sort(gid.begin(),gid.end());
std::vector<int>::iterator itv(std::unique(gid.begin(),gid.end()));
gid.erase(itv,gid.end());
```

but the final vector is only ordered.
Therefore I tried

```
std::sort(gid.begin(),gid.end());
std::vector<int>::iterator itv(std::unique(gid.begin(),gid.end()));
gid.resize( std::distance(gid.begin(),itv) );
```

and again the vector is only ordered with sort.
I also tried with the boost:

```
boost::erase(gid, boost::unique<boost::return_found_end>(boost::sort(gid)));
```

Again the same result. 
Why?

Comment: Run as expected [here](https://ideone.com/VghsbZ).

Comment: Most likely your code to check what's in the vector afterwards, is wrong.

Comment: Unless you provide code that reproduces the behavior you are observing, we will not be able to help you. The code seems correct.

Comment: As a general rule, when posting a problem here, post a simple short and complete example of your problem.  In the above case, you failed to include the means you used to diagnose there was a problem, such as a simple print loop.  And it should consist of a complete example, not snippets of code from a complete example.

Answer (score 2):

This demonstrative program is compiled successfully and yields the expected result

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> gid = { 2, 1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5 };

    std::sort( gid.begin(), gid.end() );
    std::vector<int>::iterator itv( std::unique( gid.begin(), gid.end() ) );
    gid.erase( itv, gid.end() );

    for ( int x : gid ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 5 6
```

I can suspect that you pass the vector to a function by value instead of by reference. Thus you change a copy of the original vector. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void remove_duplicates( std::vector<int> gid )
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator itv( std::unique( gid.begin(), gid.end() ) );
    gid.erase( itv, gid.end() );
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> gid = { 2, 1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5 };
    std::sort( gid.begin(), gid.end() );

    remove_duplicates( gid );

    for ( int x : gid ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
1 1 2 2 5 5 6 6
```

But if you will change the parameter declaration like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void remove_duplicates( std::vector<int> &gid )
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator itv( std::unique( gid.begin(), gid.end() ) );
    gid.erase( itv, gid.end() );
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> gid = { 2, 1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5 };
    std::sort( gid.begin(), gid.end() );

    remove_duplicates( gid );

    for ( int x : gid ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

then the result will be as expected

```
1 2 5 6
```

The other reason can be if the vector is a data member of a class and instead of using this data member you use a local definition of the vector in some member function. It is a general mistake of beginners.

So you need to check whether you indeed deal with the original vector in each of the operations.